# Using Swift, how can I create an OpenSSL HMAC digest using SHA1 and then encode with strict encode64

Tags: ruby, swift, openssl, hmac

I need to create a Base64 strict encoded representation of an OpenSSL HMAC digest using SHA1. I have the code in `Ruby`, but I need the similar code in `Swift`. Does anybody have that easy?

The code in `Ruby` is:

```
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')
hmac_digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, secret_key, canonical_string)
Base64.strict_encode64(hmac_digest)
```

As you see above, my inputs are 2 strings (`secret_key` and `canonical_string`) and I first create the digest and then I encode it.

So, what would be the correct code in `Swift` that will give the same result for the same inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a bridging header to import `CommonCrypto.h`.

And then I extended String with the following function:

```
enum HMACAlgorithm {
  case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

  func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
    var result: Int = 0
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
        result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
    case .SHA1:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
    case .SHA224:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
    case .SHA256:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
    case .SHA384:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
    case .SHA512:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
    }
    return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
  }

  func digestLength() -> Int {
    var result: CInt = 0
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
        result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA1:
        result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA224:
        result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA256:
        result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA384:
        result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA512:
        result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
    }
    return Int(result)
  }
}

extension String {
  func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
    let cKey = key.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let cData = self.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var result = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()), repeatedValue: 0)

    CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, Int(strlen(cKey!)), cData!, Int(strlen(cData!)), &result)

    let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))

    let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding76CharacterLineLength)

    return String(hmacBase64)
 }
}
```